# knights tour in c++ using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, knights-tour

I have created a class Board which deals with 2d vectors specifically for this purpose. I am trying to solve the Knight's Tour. I want to print out the thing when it is done. Using the recursive voyagingKnight() function I find that it does not do anything, does not print the result. It seems that I would want to increment the step number for the recursive call but this is not working.

The vector argument incs is a 2d vector of increments for moving the knight, in each row a row move in the first colum and a column move in the second column.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to a flaw in my reasoning here? 
The relevant code

```
    bool voyaging_knight( Board &board, int i, int j, int steps ,vector< vector<int> > &increments)
    {
        if( !newplace(theboard, i, j) ) return false; 
        board.setval(i,j,step);

        if( gone_everywhere( board, steps) )
        {
        cout <<"DONE" << endl; 
        board.showgrid();
         return true; 
        }   

        int n;
        int in, jn;   
        for(n=0; n<8; n++ )
        {
            in = i + increments[n][0]; 
            jn = j + increments[n][1]; 

            if( inboard(board, i, j)&& newplace(board,i,j) )
            {

             voyaging_knight( board, in, jn, steps+1 ,increments);

            return true; 
            }
        }


        theboard.setval(i,j,-1); 

    }
```

Comment: That's going to be pretty deep recursion of 64 calls on a normal chessboard. Are you sure you don't want to just use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change this:

```
voyagingKnight( theboard, inext, jnext, step+1 ,incs);
return true;
```

To this:

```
return voyagingKnight( theboard, inext, jnext, step+1 ,incs);
```

In addition, it seems that you need to return something (probably `false`) at the end of the function.

BTW, I'm assuming that you have all the entries in `theboard` initialized to `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want 1 continuous path made by horse movements on a (chess)-board found by backtracking.  In that case you have to pass the board by value, so each path you take has its own instance to fill.  By passing by reference, every path fills the same board, so you can never take all the steps.

Also you should pass a result by value and fill it with the positions you visited and return that from the recursive function, so each path has its own instance of resulting positions and by returning it, you end up with the final result.

You should not pass inc because that is just a helper container that doesn't change.

Comment: I updated my answer because I misinterpreted the passed inc for being the result.  You show the result (a complete finished board) at the time of reaching the last position, but for backtracking, ideally, you return a result from the recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Make the board a global variable, and build up a sequence of visited squares in a global variable too. Make sure that when retracting each tentative step you undo any changes (square visited, last step of sequence). Call your knight's tour function, make it return success if it reaches the end, and do any output after finishing.

Package the whole shebang in a file or as a class, so as to not expose private details to prying eyes.